# Why is my extension not sorting the List(Of String)?

Tags: vb.net

I have written the following extension:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub SortByLengthDescending(ByVal uList As List(Of String))

    uList.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.Length)

End Sub
```

The list of string looks like this:

```
[0] = "short text"
[1] = "very very very very long text"
```

I expect the function to sort the list so that it looks like this:

```
[0] = "very very very very long text"
[1] = "short text"
```

But that doesn't happen.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim nTest As New List(Of String)
    nTest.Add("short text")
    nTest.Add("very very very very long text")

    nTest.SortByLengthDescending
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

I have now found this:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub SortByLengthDescending(ByVal uList As List(Of String))

    Dim comparison As Comparison(Of String) =
            Function(x, y)
                Dim rslt = x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
                Return If(rslt = 0, rslt, x.CompareTo(y))
            End Function
    uList.Sort(comparison)

End Sub
```

But even this does not work right.

Here are the results:

[image]

In this example one can see that [5] is indeed longer than [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kb7E.png), so something is not right.

Edit:

I have modified my code now:

```
<Extension>
Public Sub SortByLengthDescending(ByVal uList As List(Of String))

    Dim sorted As List(Of String) = uList.ToList()
    Dim comparison As Comparison(Of String) =
            Function(x, y)
                Dim rslt = x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
                Return If(rslt = 0, rslt, x.CompareTo(y))
            End Function
    sorted.Sort(comparison)

    uList = sorted 'sorted is NOT sorted!

End Sub
```

But it does not sort it. Neither "sorted" nor "uList" are sorted.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: [Enumerable.OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) does not modify the original list. It returns a *new* sorted enumerable.

Comment: @Heinzi I have modified my code, but it still does not sort it.

Comment: You are taking the list by value. So it can’t change the reference at the call site

Comment: @tmighty `ByRef` is required for class types when you want to point the passed-in parameter to a new instance (vs simply mutating the instance you are given which is what happens with `ByVal`).  It's equivalent to `ref` in C# except that in VB there isn't a bug required at the point of call (though at least in VB6, it was legal to override `ByRef` down to `ByVal` at the point of call, I don't know if this syntax is still legal in .NET).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ByRef to change the original list:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ListExtensions
    <Extension>
    Sub OrderByLengthDescending(ByRef stringList As List(Of String))
        stringList = stringList.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Length).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```

So...

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a As New List(Of String) From {"AB", "ABC", "A"}
        a.OrderByLengthDescending()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
ABC, AB, A
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the first time that I hear that VB.NET needs ByRef. All the time, when I used ByRef in my code (coming from VB6), VB.NET would also worked with ByVal, and people in forums would even tell me that ByRef is not needed. Can you tell me why it's required in this case and in others not?

Comment: There's information on it in [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the reference to that object. You're taking its value. [This link](https://blog.penjee.com/passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-java-graphical/#:%7E:text=The%20terms%20%E2%80%9Cpass%20by%20value,where%20the%20value%20is%20stored.) explains it well.